# Why does `print <$> (print "hello")` print "hello"?

Tags: haskell

When calculating `IO (IO ())`, both `(IO ())` and `()` is calculated, so why

```hs
main :: IO (IO ())
main = print <$> (print "Hello, World!")
```

print

```hs
"Hello, World!"
```

not

```hs
IO "Hello, World!" -- ??
"Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Basically `fmap print (print "Hello World")` applies it's first parameter, the `print` function, to the result of `print "Hello World"`. That's simply the equivalent of invoking `print ()` after `print "Hello World"` action is performed.

Comment: @Redu That is correct, but note that the invocation of `print ()` never gets evaluated, nor its action performed (which would print `()` on stdout). So, "invoking `print ()` after ..." is a bit misleading (IMO).

Answer (score 21):

```
main :: IO (IO ())
main = print <$> (print "Hello, World!")
```

is equivalent, thanks to the monad laws, to

```
main :: IO (IO ())
main = do 
   result <- print "Hello, World!"
   return (print result)
```

Now, `print` always returns `()` as result, so the whole code is equivalent to

```
main :: IO (IO ())
main = do 
   _ <- print "Hello, World!"
   return (print ())
```

Finally, the result of `main` is simply discarded. That is, the last line could be `return (putStrLn "this is ignored")` and have the same effect.

Hence the code will only execute the first `print "Hello, World!"`.

I would recommend that you always define `main :: IO ()`. Haskell allows us to declare `main :: IO AnyTypeHere`, but this is (IMO) confusing.

I would also recommend you use `putStrLn`, and not `print` to print strings, since the latter will quote and escape the whole string.

Comment: I'd add that `f <$> a ≡ a >>= \r -> return $ f r` is not just a specific thing to this situation, but actually holds for any monad.